# Need help verifying a PDF exists from a URL

Tags: java, selenium, pdfbox

My goal is to verify that a link to a PDF loads properly.   I'm new to selenium, java, etc.

I tried both with URL and FILE after the load

```
       PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new FILE ("https://xxxxxcx/iPledgeUI/rems/pdf/resources/iPledge_REMS_Non_Compliance_Action_Policy.pdf"));
       PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
       String text = pdfStripper.getText(doc);
       doc.close();
```

Expected result would be that the file gets loaded from the URL

Here is what I am getting

https:/xxxxxxxx/iPledgeUI/rems/pdf/resources/iPledge_REMS_Non_Compliance_Action_Policy.pdf (No such file or directory)

Comment: Well....there is no such file at the link you provided. Are you sure it's right?

Answer (score 2):

That isn't a file, that is an URL. Load these with

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.InputStream;

…

InputStream is = new URL("....").openStream(); // will throw here if URL doesn't work
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(is); // will throw here if PDF malformed or empty file
…
is.close();
```

If the URL doesn't exist you'll get an exception. (Exception handling code not included here)

Comment: @CrazyHarry If the answer solved your problem, please click on the checkmark to make it the accepted answer. If not, make a comment why the answer didn't help or needs further improvement. I noticed that none of the answers on your other questions has the checkmark.